# How to generate continuos report card?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I have following table and data in MS.SQL Server

```
Id StudentName Roll SubjectName FM  PM  OM
1  Peter       1    English     100 40  80
2  Peter       1    Math        100 40  95
3  Peter       1    Science     100 40  75
4  Mike        2    English     100 40  75
5  Mike        2    Math        100 40  57
6  Mike        2    Science     100 40  48
7  Bella       3    English     100 40  85
8  Bella       3    Math        100 40  75
9  Bella       3    Science     100 40  65
```

How to print this data as continuous report using using ASP.net data report?

I used list control in report, but it is repeating all the rows as separate report. Here I want to print only 3 reports as per the Student.

Answer (score 0):

We can groupwise the list control to solve the above problem.